# need to modify the below oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below script  ,  i want to modify  it such a way lets say if it is executed first time then it will create the column  but lets say if it is executed second time then it will show fail message which is not correct it should show the message that column is created and also if there comes any exception lets say column i s not created due to some technical exception then it should show fail message , please advise how to achieve this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO L_COL_EXISTS FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'TOR' and TABLE_NAME='AVOICE';    
    IF L_COL_EXISTS = 1
    THEN          
      outcome := 'Success';
    ELSE
      outcome := 'Fail';
    END IF;  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(outcome);
```

folks please advise

Comment: how do you add the column? Do you know the statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it can help you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_column
(
   v_table_name  IN VARCHAR2,
   v_column_name IN VARCHAR2,
   v_column_type IN VARCHAR2
) 
IS
  v_column_exists     pls_integer;
  v_ddl_str           varchar2(1024);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT count(*)
        INTO   v_column_exists
        FROM   user_tab_columns
        WHERE  table_name = upper(v_table_name)
               and column_name = upper(v_column_name);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RAISE;
    END;

    if v_column_exists = 0 then 
        v_ddl_str := 'alter table ' || v_table_name || ' add ( ' ||  v_column_name || ' ' || v_column_type || ')';
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alter_str;
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
              dbms_output.put_line ('something wrong');
              RAISE;
        END;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line ('Column exists');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;    
END add_column;
/
```